# What to buy for Sukkot

Tags: halacha, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

If one is poor, should he buy an Etrog for Sukkot or food for his family? I am researching the halacha with regard to this as a response to the story by Agnon.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Perhaps you should consider editing in what story you are referring to. Also consider the facts that the mitzvah is to take *all four* species - just buying an esrog might not be enough; that this question only applies on the first day, when it must belong to you; and that one may give his friend an esrog on condition that he return it when he is done, as it will be considered the friend's in the meantime.

Comment: Is there an Etrog available in his community that he could borrow for a few minutes each day?

Comment: Many kehillot (especially Chabad ones) have a community sukkah and a set of arba minim that everyone can use. So technically one doesn't have to buy anything if they live in one of those kehillot.